# How to re-map an array to use in Ant Design Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, antd

I have this code structure:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Lebron',
    sports: 'Basketball',
  },
  {
    name: 'Durant',
    sports: 'Basketball',
  },
  {
    name: 'Federrer',
    sports: 'Tennis',
  },
  {
    name: 'Nadal',
    sports: 'Tennis',
  },
];
```

and I'm trying to transform it into this:

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: 'Select All',
    key: 'All',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Basketball',
        key: 'Basketball',
        children: [
          {
            title: 'Lebron',
            key: 'Lebron',
          },
          {
            title: 'Durant',
            key: 'Durant',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Tennis',
        key: 'Tennis',
        children: [
          {
            title: 'Federrer',
            key: 'Federrer',
          },
          {
            title: 'Nadal',
            key: 'Nadal',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

to use in Ant Design Tree [link](https://ant.design/components/tree/).

Right now my plan is to get all the sports like this:

```
let sports = data.map(({ sports }) => sports); 
sports = [...new Set(sports)];
```

but after that I have no idea on what should be my next step to achieve the `treeData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accumulate all sports to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where each sport is a key and each value for the sport is an array of associated `name`s. Once you have built the Map, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert your map into your desired `children` array. This can be done by providing a mapping function as the second argument to Array.from(), and using it to convert each entry (`[key, value]`) pair to an object of your desired structure.

See example below:

```js
const data = [ { name: 'Lebron', sports: 'Basketball', }, { name: 'Durant', sports: 'Basketball', }, { name: 'Federrer', sports: 'Tennis', }, { name: 'Nadal', sports: 'Tennis', }, ];

const children = Array.from(data.reduce((m, {name, sports}) =>
  m.set(sports, [...(m.get(sports) || []), name])
, new Map), ([key, arr]) => ({title: key, key, children: arr.map(title => ({title, key: title}))}));

const treeData = [{title: 'Select All', key: 'All', children}];
console.log(treeData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Lebron',
    sports: 'Basketball',
  },
  {
    name: 'Durant',
    sports: 'Basketball',
  },
  {
    name: 'Federrer',
    sports: 'Tennis',
  },
  {
    name: 'Nadal',
    sports: 'Tennis',
  },
];

const dataMap: Record<string, string[]> = {};
data.forEach(({ name, sports }) => {
    dataMap[sports] ??= []
    dataMap[sports].push(name)
})

const treeData = [{
    title: 'Select All',
    key: 'All',    
    children: Object.entries(dataMap).map(([sport, names]) => ({
        title: sport,
        key: sport,
        children: names.map(name => ({
            title: name,
            key: name
        }))
    }))
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a two-steps way of get the children of your final object:

First, use a reduce to create an object of sports/children, where children matches what you have in your final output:

```
const middle = data.reduce((transformed, item) => {
  if (!transformed[item.sports]) {
    transformed[item.sports] = [];
  }
  transformed[item.sports].push({
    title: item.name,
    key: item.name
  });
  return transformed;
}, {});
```

Then map the results of the reduce function to reshape the object:

```
const results = Object.entries(middle).map(([key, children]) => ({
  title: key,
  key,
  children
}));
```